# Why is it necessary to indicate identifying or non-identifying relationships in an ERD?

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key, erd

In an ERD, a weak/non-identifying relationship is one that connects two strong entities, and is indicated with a dashed line. A strong/identifying relationship is one that connects a strong entity to a weak entity (a weak entity is one that contains the foreign key [FK] from its related entity as a component of its own primary key [PK]), and is indicated by a solid line.

My question is, **So what? Why is it so important to distinguish between weak/non-identifying relationships versus strong/identifying relationships that ERD designers are supposed to make that distinction with dashed versus solid lines, respectively?** Why does it matter so much?

For me, every element and convention in an ERD should add necessary information that either translates directly into the database design (that is, DDL SQL statements), or at least explains information that is important but not necessarily obvious (and example of this last case would be naming the relationships--they do not translate into SQL, but they are very useful for understanding the ERD). Here is a sample ERD for the sake of discussion (modified from [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699868/basic-database-design-optional-participation)):

[image: sample ERD]

I have considered this a lot, and to me, the only information that solid versus dashed lines add is already adequately conveyed in the following conventions:

- Whether or not an FK is part of an entity's PK (PK,FK1 or PK,FK2 in the sample ERD).
- Whether or not the FK is a **required attribute (bold)** or optional attribute (not bold).

As far as I can see, the solid versus dashed relationship line adds no additional useful information. Rather than adding information, this convention is non-intuitive and is very confusing. As just one example of the confusion they cause, there are many duplicate questions here on StackOverflow that ask which is which; here are just a few examples:

- [How to identify a strong vs weak relationship on ERD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675127/how-to-identify-a-strong-vs-weak-relationship-on-erd)
- [What's the difference between identifying and non-identifying relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships)
- [Still Confused About Identifying vs. Non-Identifying Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814469/still-confused-about-identifying-vs-non-identifying-relationships)
- [Identifying vs Non-Identifying Relationships (Again!!!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444083/identifying-vs-non-identifying-relationships-again)

Can anyone explain to me what additional information that convention adds that is not contained in the fact that an FK might or might not be part of a PK? I am seriously considering just ignoring the convention completely (that is, I want to start drawing my ERDs with all solid lines), but I would really appreciate it if someone could point out something important that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Understanding weak/strong entities/relationships is useful for determining if/how foreign key constraints should propagate deletions/updates.  Deletions tend to cascade to weak entities.

Comment: @reaanb, I've edited the original question to add a sample ERD and emphasized my particular conventions (I mark FKs and I indicated required or optional attributes). So, with those clarifications, how would the solid/dashed line indicate propagation of FK constraints beyond what the conventions I specified already indicate?

Comment: "Every element and convention in an ERD should..." is misconcieved. A good relational information modeling method would, but [ER doesn't understand the relational model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27272088/3404097). It makes unnecesary & ill-advised arbitrary distinctions between entities, relationships and properties. It limits entity types to some base tables whereas every superkey of every subexpression identifies some application entity type. Per @reaanb a "weak" entity's existence depends on some consequently (relatively) "strong" entity's, relevant to inserting & deleting them together.

Comment: You are using one of the derivatives of the original ER method that warps the use of "relationship" & "weak" vs "strong". An ER "relationship" is an application relationship/relation (denoted by a diamond), ie it corresponds to a "relation" qua association and is represented by a "relation" qua table. It does *not* mean entity id FK (denoted by a line, corresponding to an entity type's role in the relationship). Read about Entity-Role Modeling, very close to relational modeling, & how various "ER" methods are expressed by it.

Comment: That is not an ERD. Ubiquitously, it is claimed to be an ERD by many methods that are not ER but claim to be ER. Naturally they are related closely to (true Chen) ER because they have similar goals. They call a FK a "relationship" but in ER a relationship (aka relationship instance) is a tuple of entities participating in an association (aka relationship class) (aka relationship!). The boxes in the diagram correspond to boxes/entities & diamonds/associations in ER, all represented by tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convention used in ER model diagrams is that referencing (foreign key) attributes are not shown at all unless they are part of a primary key. If referencing attributes are required they are supposed to be implied by the existence of a relationship line. Accordingly, there is no standard or generally agreed ER notation for foreign key attributes even when they are part of a primary key. The case where referencing attributes are needed in order to identify instances of an entity is often called out on ER diagrams by using a dotted relationship line. The motivation here is presumably that "primary" key attributes are deemed to be mandatory and significant so their dependence on other things is also significant.

If your diagram shows foreign key attributes in some other way then the distinction between identfiying/non-identifying relationships is unimportant in my view. Whatever notation you use, ultimately what matters is that your audience understands your diagram correctly.

Comment: You said, "A convention used in ER model diagrams is that referencing (foreign key) attributes are not shown at all unless they are part of a primary key." If I understand you correctly, you are saying that some ERDs don't provide any indication of foreign keys (e.g. by labeling them "FK"), so in such cases the solid/dashed lines do convey critical information; but if FKs are labeled, then the solid/dashed lines are not necessary. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That's what I mean, yes.

Comment: Partially based on your answer and someone else's comments, I've edited the original question to add a sample ERD and emphasized my particular conventions (I mark FKs and I indicated required or optional attributes). I don't know if those clarifications would change your answer.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion an ERD is not so much about some database. It is about me understanding the segment of the world I am dealing with, especially lifecycle of things.

A spreadsheet cell is identified by its row and column. It exists only because both its row and its column exist. As soon as you delete / shred / burn either its row or its column, you have just done the same with its cells. Or you might cut up the sheet with scissors into all its cells, however, at that point they can not be neatly summarized or sorted, their formulae lost their meaning, because they are no longer spreadsheet cells, they lost their such identity.

A green live leaf is identified by the plant it grows on. In fall the leaves fall. You probably could not tell which fell from which tree, they lost their identity of a live leaf, which must have a tree to cling on. Or if you tear off a live leaf, you cannot put it back onto another tree. If you kill/fell the tree, all green live leaves also die.

If you find a christmas decoration on a tree, and later you find something strikingly similar on another tree, it could be the very same decoration moved over. It is not in an identifying relationship with the tree. You can also just put it in the attic with no tree anywhere near.

If you find a leaf growing on a tree, and later a totally identically looking leaf growing on another tree, you can be sure, it is not the same leaf.

I think the difference between the tree's relationship with its leaves and that with its decorations is pretty profound. If you design a computer system keeping record of trees, leaves, and decorations, I think it is useful to indicate this difference on your design diagrams.

Developers will then know what the constructor method signatures will be. There will be no leaf constructor without a mandatory tree argument. But there will be a decoration constructor without a tree argument. There will be no moveToTree method in the leaf class. There could be a moveToTree method in the decoration class. You could optimize your garbage collector to quickly identify all leaf objects whose tree variable points to a dead tree, and reclaim them. This optimization is not applicable to decoration objects.

If you elect to use a relational database for persistence, developers will know that the decoration table's FK to tree table will have to be optional, and not a PK field. But the live leaf table's FK to the tree table will be mandatory, and part of its composite PK.

And contrasting the leaf-tree identifying relationship with a mandatory non-identifying relationship: for a HIV virus specimen it is not optional to have a virus host, outside one it desintegrates. However, it can be transferred to another host, so although mandatory, the relationship is not identifying.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is incoherent relative to the question asked.

Comment: This question is kind of philosophical to me, (and frankly any question may be deeply pondered to find analogies of life, football, and what not 8^).